# "estimated_time" on baking right is not constant

Tags: baking, baking-rights, block

Yesterday I noticed that `estimated_time` on baking rights is not constant. It looks like it changes at the start of every block.

**Can someone explain why that happens?**

For example:

```
{estimated_time: "2019-03-21T00:20:30Z", level: 64633}
```

And then, at the start of next block:

```
{estimated_time: "2019-03-21T00:23:30Z", level: 64633}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when the network is running late.

This **`estimated_time`** is computed on the "every baker at priority 0 will bake" hypothesis.

Each time a block is baked by the baker of priority 1, it is baked later and every following block has to be baked "later"...

[Reference](https://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/api/odoc/_html/tezos-embedded-protocol-003-PsddFKi3/Tezos_embedded_raw_protocol_003_PsddFKi3/Delegate_services/Baking_rights/index.html)

Thanks to **@Pierre Boutillier** for helping with this

Comment: Thank you. Could you please provide a pointer to where this logic is implemented as a reference ?

Comment: Updated my answer with a link

https://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/api/odoc/_html/tezos-embedded-protocol-003-PsddFKi3/Tezos_embedded_raw_protocol_003_PsddFKi3/Delegate_services/Baking_rights/index.html